# mv: cannot remove directory: Directory not empty

Tags: directory, mv

Running the command

```
/data/jritchie$ mv ~/jenkins_dev /data/jritchie/jenkins_dev
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors like the following:

```
mv: cannot remove `/home/jritchie/jenkins_dev/plugins/valgrind/WEB-INF/lib': Directory not empty
```

This is similar to errors returned by [rm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48227/cannot-remove-some-directory-directory-not-empty).

My question is, does this error mean that my files were all successfully moved to the new location, but removing them from the old location failed? Or that they didn't get moved at all? Can I safely remove the old files with `rm -r ~/jenkins_dev`?

Comment: did you try `sudo mv ~/jenkins_dev /data/jritchie/jenkins_dev`, maybe you do not have permissions?

Comment: I don't have superuser access, but I believe I have permissions to read & write all the files in both locations.

Comment: I think for directories you need `+x` permission so the command can enter the directory.

Comment: I think I also have that permisssion:
    `$ ls -lh ~/jenkins_dev/plugins/valgrind/WEB-INF/` gives
   `total 4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 jritchie software 4.0K Oct  7 12:06 lib`

Comment: according to your listing, `root` has all privileges, other users from `root` group do not have `+w` permission as all other users. It seems you cannot write into directory therefore files cannot be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/269775/mv-directory-not-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if there is a file/folder in there that you don't own.  Assuming bash and all file names are nicely behaved, something like:

```
for file in $(find ~/jenkins_dev); do stat -c '%U %n' $file;done | grep -v jritchie
```

If something pops up then you need to get the owner (or sysadmin) to handle it for you.

Comment: The result of that command is nothing - all of the files have me as the owner.

Comment: @JacobRitchie, oic, then maybe the problem is you have files in `/data/jritchie/jenkins_dev` already and `mv` doesn't want to merge them (this was suggested in the comments)?

Comment: Coming back to this a few days later, I think that you were right - there were a few files that I didn't see initially (http://serverfault.com/questions/201294/nfsxxxx-files-appearing-what-are-those).