# how to kill java process forcefully and remove directory which is used by that process

Tags: java, rm, kill, pkill

I have one use case where I am killing a java process with `pkill java`, and after that, I want to remove certain directories. I have used `rm -rf /pathtofolder` but it gives:

```
rm: cannot remove '/pathtofolder': Directory not empty
```

Is there any way I can kill java forcefully, which allows me to remove directories (which are on an NFS share)? I am not sure how `fuser` will help here, or if I should use `sleep 20` between `pkill` and `rm` commands.

Please guide.

Comment: Are you using some filesystem suchs as `nfs`,`sshfs`, etc? Since you mentioned `fuser` maybe you already saw [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48357/414186). Maybe you are right and you will have to make a delay between `pkill` and `rm`.

Comment: Btw, I supposed that by having this in your question: `"pkill java" & after that` you meant `"pkill java"` **and** `after that`. Or are you actually running the command `pkill java &`? Because when you use `command &` what the shell does is running the process `command` in background.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yes it is NFS, and I am using pkill java. I suppose killing java process needs time to terminate it fully, but I want to know how I can kill it forcefully.

Comment: And are you sure your process is being killed by `pkill java`?  Because with that command it should kill any process whose matches the pattern `java` so maybe it will kill several java process instead. I suggest you use `kill -9 pid_of_java_process` (or `sudo kill -9 ...`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thank you, I will try that, once again thank you for your support & time

Comment: You're welcome! You can also check if your directory is busy by using `lsof`. Maybe something like: `lsof /pathtofolder` could show what process are using that directory (run `lsof` after killing the java process)